# What happens, when an IRQ handler runs during I2C (SMB) (ioctl) operations (read/write) in LINUX

Tags: linux, interrupt, i2c

Given, that an SMB_readWord(..) from an sensor device is underway and a timer interrupt occurs somewhat in the middle of it. What's going to happen?
The read fails?
The interrupt is deferred by the kernel?

Comment: It depends what timer function will do. Does it interfere the transfer? Obviously you can't call I²C commands (or any other **sleeping** calls) from timer handler.

Comment: Hi, No, the timer function will just set a flag and has nothing to do w/ I2C transfers, called form main()... My concern is that I2C operations have to comply w/ certain timings. When a write/read operation is underway (using fread/fwrite) and the timer INT occurs, will it interfere, or not?

Comment: Then it depends on the FIFO of I²C host controller. If it has enough FIFO, nothing bad happens.

Comment: Hi, there is no host controller! I use the IOCTL of the OrangePi board

Comment: Seems you do **not** understand how hardware is made and designed and how OS uses it. If it has no I²C host controller, you can't do anything on that board except bit-banging the protocol over 2 GPIO lines (but I know that the board **has** I²C host controller).

Comment: Well, OK! The question is, do I have to dive into all and everything, if I want to use it as an end-user, or can I trust that the SoC an OS Kernel Designers have done their job and I use e.g. an I2C implementation w/out having to learn, how the device driver and the HW has been built?? Do I have to know everything about Camshaft timing, when driving my car? If I always would have to know everything about everything, I would go nowhere!

Comment: Then why do you ask a question about FIFO? Just don't be bothered with it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the driver.  Pick the chip you are interested in and read the host controller driver.

For most of them I expect the hardware carries on doing its thing without needing continuous use of the processor.  Obviously they do need the processor eventually to complete the system call but that is usually timed to occur at a point in the transaction that can be safely delayed by a few microseconds while an interrupt is being served.

Comment: May be I had 2b more precise. I wanted to know, what happens in the LINUX  (Debian) kernel on e.g. an xy-PI while serving I2C traffic and an arising INT. Sorry, if I appear 2b lazy, but I'm not a kernel expert and it would take a lot, diving in kernel drivers 4me.

Comment: Please do not use numbers instead of words, it makes you look like very childish.  If you do not want to learn any details then the answer for you is "it just works".